# How to find what time a packet reached at Azure IOT hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have a device which is sending data via IOT hub to Eventhub and then to other data layers. The data is in JSON format. I could identify some delay to reach the data to my Database, compared to the time the packet is actually generated at the device(We have a time in the JSON packet). I need to identify the ingestion time of a packet when it reaches IOT hub to analyze and find where the delay is happening. How we can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every message gets a couple of [System Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct#system-properties-of-d2c-iot-hub-messages) added by IoT Hub. What you are looking for is `iothub-enqueuedtime`